# W3C validator sees errors that don't exist?

Tags: html, w3c

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwindowsnaarlinux.nl%2F%3Fpagina%3Dwelkedistro%23welkedistro&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Is the W3C Validator seeing things that're not there, or am I growing blind at a young age?
It says `No p element in scope but a p end tag seen.` 5 times but every time there's clearly an opening *and* closing tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your document has a header tag inside of the `<p>` tag. This is not valid. When the header tag is seen, the `<p>` is closed. Therefore you are left with the a dangling `</p>`. Move your open `<p>` to AFTER the header tags.

Comment: It seems you keep changing the page, but I can still see it on line 95: <p><h2><a href="http://www.ubuntu.com/" target="_blank"><img src="./img/distros/ubuntu.png" alt="" style="height: 16px;" /> Ubuntu</a></h2>

Comment: Ah, now I see it, thanks. Now it's time for me to go on to the next batch of erros that just cropped up! :p